# Select decimal numbers after . that are higher than 0

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a float column "percent1" that has various percentages.
Example:

```
Percent1
32.0000
20.0000
31.4000
25.1000
30.0000
```

What I want to achieve is a select that pulls all the percentages that are higher than 0 after the dot. Example:

```
31.4000
25.1000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select * 
from thetable
where thecolumn <> floor(thecolumn)
```

`floor` returns the largest integer (ie no decimal places) that is less than or equal to the argument. So if the value of the column is different from the value without decimal places, it has some decimal places that are different from `0`

Comment: Thank you so much this is what i needed

Answer (score 5):

Using modulo division:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE Percent1 % 1 != 0;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/AnmoLwHT)**

Comment: I think this is the fastest and most resource effective way of doing this.

Comment: This is actually the opposite of what is being asked. The correct WHERE would be: 
```WHERE Percent1 % 1 != 0;```